# Django links, url parameters overwriting

Tags: django

I've got django template with table/list with sorting action:

```
<a href="?order_by=name">Name</a>
```

and later I've got paging:

```
 <a href="?page=1">first</a>
```

What I want to achieve is a link:
http://localhost:8000/list/?page=3&order_by=name

but, while  - clicking a link, I can get either page or order_by.

How to solve it the 'django way'? (for 2 and more parameters).

More details -

```
def list_view(request): 
    items_list = model.objects.all() 
    # Filter
    request_filter = request.GET.get('filter',"")
    if request_filter: 
        items_list = items_list.filter(model__icontains=request_filter)

    # Paging
    paginator = Paginator(list, 2) # Show 2 items per page.
    page_number = request.GET.get('page',1)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    items_list = paginator.page(page_number)


    return render(request,'list.html', {'list' : items_list, 'filter':request_filter, 'page_obj': page_obj})
```

and template: (related parts)

```
  <form action="" method="GET"> 
        <input type="text"  name="filter" value={{filter}} >  
        <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="submit">Filtruj</button>
    </form>


<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a href="?order_by=name">Name</a></th> 

etc </table>

<div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please share the view and template.

Comment: Suggestion: don't call things `list` and `filter`. These are python built-ins.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - shared.

Comment: Keeping the same page for a different ordering however looks a bit odd?

Comment: Maybe, so lets focus on:  filtering and sorting. They should be available together, ie. you could  filter data and then want to sort result.